# On hover Slidedown the child div

Tags: jquery

I want to slidedown the child div on hover of parent div respectively. I have made a function in which I tried to slidedown but it is not working. I want to slidedown the nth div on hover on main div on respective basis. I have written the function in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main").hover(function() {
    myfunction();
  });

  function myfunction(index) {
    $(".main").each(function() {
      $($(this) > div: nth - of -type(2)).slideDown(2000);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.main > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button style="margin: 15px 0">Get Result</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your selector in `myfunction()` is invalid syntax. You need to use `find()` and place the `nth-of-type()` selector in there. Try this:

```css
.main > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button style="margin: 15px 0">Get Result</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> I want to hover the child div on parent div respectively

In this case don't use `each()` to loop over all the `.main` elements. Just look for the children within the currently hovered element. Also use `slideToggle()` to slide them back up when the mouse leaves the parent element:

```css
.main > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: lavender;
}

.main > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: transform, max-height 0.5s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.main:hover > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  max-height: 100px;
}

button {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button>Get Result</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that this can be done in pure CSS, with no JS required:

```css
.main > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: lavender;
}

.main > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: transform, max-height 0.5s;
  max-height: 0;
}

.main:hover > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  max-height: 100px;
}

button {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 main">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3>Lavender</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button>Get Result</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This function is working same as before, not giving the required result. I want to hover the child div on parent div respectively. This is hovering all the divs at the same time.

Comment: That's because your code tells it to as you iterate over them all using `each()`

Comment: What i do to get the desired result. That means on hover of one single parent div its child div display and not others.